# Rellenar un array con valores de otro array

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo una duda sobre los arrays en javascript, busco rellenar un array vacio con los elementos de otro array, esto es posible?

Leí acerca de metodos como `.push(array)` o `.concat(array)` y no me sirven en esta situacion.
Cabe aclarar que lo que busco es **modificar un array existente, no crear uno nuevo** como es el caso de la funcion `.concat(array)`.
Tampoco me sirve la funcion `.push(array)` porque me devuleve el array que antes estaba vacío, con el array con elementos dentro. Yo quiero el array vacío, con **los elementos** del array lleno, **no con el array entero en sí**, espero haberme explicado.

Con un simple ejemplo sobre como hacerlo me basta, yo despues lo aplico a mi programa. Gracias de antemano.

Diego

Comment: Si agregas lo que llevas será mejor recibida tu pregunta

Comment: porque push me devuelve el array que antes estaba vacio, con un array lleno dentro. yo necesito que los elementos del array lleno esten en el vacio, no que el array entero este dentro del vacio.

Comment: tendria que tener mayor explicacion un ejemplo de lo que intentastes y el resultado deseado por lo pronto te invito a leer [`Array.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/fill)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes pasar cada uno de los elementos

```
let ar_empty = [];
ar_filled.map((item) => {
    ar_empty.push(item);
    return item;
});

console.log(ar_empty);
```

Comment: buenisimo, lo habia pensado, pero me costaba llevarlo a codigo, de mas esta decir que me estoy familiarizando con js, muchas gracias jonathan

Comment: Pienso que sería mejor usar el forEach ya que no estás utilizando el ítem retornado, solo iteras

Answer (score 3):

Simplemente por medio del *spread operator* puedes llenar el vector vacío con los valores del vector que esta relleno; de esta forma:

```js
    let primerVector = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    
    let vectorVacio = [...primerVector]
    console.log(vectorVacio)
```

Lo que hace este operador es tomar el elemento anterior(el vector) que es un elemento iterable y lo *expande* dentro del vector vacío.

En caso de que dicho elemento no sea iterable tendrías un error como este:

> "TypeError: number 1 is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Por otro lado no veo como el uso de `push()` te va a colocar un array dentro de otro, partiendo del hecho de que primero deberías iterar el que esta *lleno* y posterior por cada iteración entonces rellenar el vector vacío con el valor recuperado por cada vuelta.

Mira este ejemplo:

```
let vectorVacio = []
let primerVector = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

for (numero of primerVector) {
  vectorVacio.push(numero)
}

console.log(vectorVacio)
```

Resultado

```
Array(6)
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
3: 4
4: 5
5: 6
length: 6
```

Como puedes observar la salida de la consola nos devuelve el vector que antes estaba vacío con los valores agregados, teniendo este una sola dimensión

Comment: gracias por el aporte,(basandome en las variables de tu ejemplo) mi falla era que habia hecho algo asi:
`vectorVacío.push(primerVector)`